# The meaning of cut in the sentence

Tags: meaning

The following quote is from *Godfather* book

> As the weeks went by and he became busier and busier with getting the
>   script ready, casting the movie and working out production details,
>   Johnny Fontane forgot about his voice, his not being able to sing. Yet
>   when the academy award nominations came out and he found himself one
>   of the candidates, he was depressed because he was not asked to sing
>   one of the songs nominated for the Oscar at the ceremony that would be
>   televised nationally. But he shrugged it offand kept working. He had
>   no hope of winning the Academy Award now that his Godfather was no
>   longer able to put pressure on, but getting the nomination had some
>   value.
>
> *The record he and Nino had cut, the one of Italian songs, was selling
>   much better that anything he had cut lately, but he knew that it was
>   Nino's success more than his.*

I'm a little confused by the last sentence I provided, particualrly by the meaining of *cut* in here. What is that?

The thing is that I'm used to use that word with vegatables. Like cut vegatables or something similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this context, *cut* means "recorded and produced." See [Macmillan Definition #11](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/cut_1#cut_45):

> **cut** (*verb*) `MUSIC` if a musician or band cuts a record, they record it

In the realm of music, *cut* can be used as a [noun](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/cut_2) as well:

> **cut** (*noun*) `MUSIC`a piece of music that has been recorded

Given the time period when *The Godfather* was written, the "record" probably refers to a vinyl record that would be played on a turntable:

[image]

Comment: And in the days before the advent of tape recorders, recording sound involved literal "cutting": sound caused vibration in a stylus which carved a trace of its vibrations in a  continuous groove in a wax (later shellac, and then vinyl) master disc.

Comment: +1 Good picture, showing the cutting process. I got that.

Comment: @Dmitry - Actually, that's not showing the cutting process. That's just the finished product playing on a record player (a.k.a. a turntable).

Comment: It's probably also worth nothing that "cut" is often still used today by analogy to describe recording or editing music, even for digital media.

Comment: @J.R. Well, I thought that the recorder's head was actually cutting the disk. At my old vynil disks we could see a little scratches made during recording with such a player. Why don't?

Answer (score 3):

"Cut" can have many meanings. From context, it appears one of them is "cut a record," meaning "make a record" (like, of music). I'd guess the etymology of this is that a vinyl record has grooves cut into it; before tape became more common, you literally "cut" the sound into the record.